# How to delete rows from dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe with ("ID", "Month" and "status"). Status is regarding "Churn"= 1 and 'Not Churn" = 2. I want to delete all rows for ID's who are already churned except the first appearance.  For example:

Dataframe

```
    ID      Month   Status
    2310    201708  2
    2310    201709  2
    2310    201710  1
    2310    201711  1
    2310    201712  1
    2310    201801  1
    2311    201704  2
    2311    201705  2
    2311    201706  2
    2311    201707  2
    2311    201708  2
    2311    201709  2
    2311    201710  1
    2311    201711  1
    2311    201712  1
    2312    201708  2
    2312    201709  2
    2312    201710  2
    2312    201711  1
    2312    201712  1
    2312    201801  1
```

After deleting I should have the following dataframe

```
    ID      Month   Status
    2310    201708  2
    2310    201709  2
    2310    201710  1

    2311    201704  2
    2311    201705  2
    2311    201706  2
    2311    201707  2
    2311    201708  2
    2311    201709  2
    2311    201710  1

    2312    201708  2
    2312    201709  2
    2312    201710  2
    2312    201711  1
```

I tried the following- first to find min date for each customer ID and status=1

```
    df1=df[df.Status==1].groupby('ID')['Month'].min()
```

then I have to delete all rows for each ID with status 1 greater than min value for MOnth.

Comment: why do you have results for `2311` for status `2` when it changes to `1` later on, shouldn't that get dropped

Comment: I have to keep all rows until the first time changed to 1. So I keep all rows for ID with value 2 and first row when the status changed to 1

Comment: can you update your post with that logic?

Comment: Please share some data in a way that makes it easy for others to test solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're familiar with [`DataFrame.idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html) to get the indices of the elements of the most recent month, you could try:

```
# find minimum months
min_df = df.groupby(['ID','Status'])['Month'].idxmin().reset_index(drop=True)
# find indices of status 2 rows
df2 = df[df['Status'].eq(2)].index.to_series()
# append indices together
idx_df = min_df.append(df2).drop_duplicates()
# filter indices
df_new = df.iloc[idx_df].sort_index()
```

---

```
print(df_new)                                                                        
      ID   Month  Status
0   2310  201708       2
1   2310  201709       2
2   2310  201710       1
6   2311  201704       2
7   2311  201705       2
8   2311  201706       2
9   2311  201707       2
10  2311  201708       2
11  2311  201709       2
12  2311  201710       1
15  2312  201708       2
16  2312  201709       2
17  2312  201710       2
18  2312  201711       1
```

**Update**

Or, you may think about using [`GroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['ID','Status']).apply(lambda x: (x['Status'].eq(2)) | (x['Month'].eq(x['Month'].min())))
df1 = df1.reset_index(level=['ID','Status'], drop=True)
df_new = df.loc[df1]
```

---

```
print(df_new)                                                                                                                                              
      ID   Month  Status
0   2310  201708       2
1   2310  201709       2
2   2310  201710       1
6   2311  201704       2
7   2311  201705       2
8   2311  201706       2
9   2311  201707       2
10  2311  201708       2
11  2311  201709       2
12  2311  201710       1
15  2312  201708       2
16  2312  201709       2
17  2312  201710       2
18  2312  201711       1
```

**Update 2**

However, if you're simply wanting to remove all of the status 1 rows that come after the row with the earliest month, then you could simply `sort_values` and `transform`:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['ID','Month']).reset_index(drop=True) 
df = df[df.groupby('ID')['Status'].transform(lambda x: ~(x.duplicated() & (x == 1)))]
```

---

```
print(df)                                                              
      ID   Month  Status
0   2310  201708       2
1   2310  201709       2
2   2310  201710       1
6   2311  201704       2
7   2311  201705       2
8   2311  201706       2
9   2311  201707       2
10  2311  201708       2
11  2311  201709       2
12  2311  201710       1
15  2312  201708       2
16  2312  201709       2
17  2312  201710       2
18  2312  201711       1
```

Comment: It doesn't work on real dataframe. The rows with status 1 are still there

Comment: Could you provide any info about those remaining status 1 rows? In your example, the IDs and months were already ordered. If they aren't ordered in your actual dataframe, you may not receive the expected output.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I gave the example which could be solved with 'shift'. I hope that now is clearer.

Comment: I think I understand what you're wanting now and updated my response. Let me know if there are any issues with the current answer.

Comment: That's it! Thank you.

Meanwhile, I found another issue with Churn and not Churn statuses. 

Situation 1. The customer was inactive (Status = 1 ) and then become active (Status = 2). 

I have to delete all rows for each customer with status 1 if that was before status 2

Situation 2. The customer was only in status = 1 during the observed period. So I have to delete all rows for each customer
with status 1 if there are no other statuses during the observed period

Comment: Situation 3. Solved - delete all rows with status = 1 after Churn except the first appearance. 
I used the first example
df[df.groupby('ID')['Status'].transform(lambda x: ~(x.duplicated() & (x == 1)))]

but I added before that
df=df.sort_values(by=['ID','Month'])
dw_df.reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect your third situation. However, I don't think it's good practice to keep updating an answer to reflect many different questions that aren't reflected in the initial question. If this answer solved your initial question, I would mark this answer as resolved. Then, ask your other questions in separate posts. I would be happy to help you with those questions as well :)

Comment: Tnx, dkhara, you are right. You solved my problem. I opened new issue with additional questions 
'Deleting rows based on groupby conditions'

Comment: Great, could you please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of this answer if it helped

Comment: done. could you also see this second question? Probably you can find the answer

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use `groupby` with `transform` with boolean logic and then boolean indexing:

```
df[df.groupby('ID')['Status'].transform(lambda x: ~(x.duplicated() & (x == 1)))]
```

Output:

```
      ID   Month  Status
0   2310  201708       2
1   2310  201709       2
2   2310  201710       1
6   2311  201704       2
7   2311  201705       2
8   2311  201706       2
9   2311  201707       2
10  2311  201708       2
11  2311  201709       2
12  2311  201710       1
15  2312  201708       2
16  2312  201709       2
17  2312  201710       2
18  2312  201711       1
```